What else can cause a fire to go out besides rain?
The building I constructed has two fires, but for no apparent reason, they sometimes go out and start burning again. Is this a bug in the early access version of the game?

There is no rain, but the fires are covered with a roof.
The building is an exact copy of the house seen here (YouTube video).

There is plenty of fuel.
Both fires burn and go out, seeming independently.


Without having watched the entire video in full, are the two fireplaces the ones at the back of the house?
My best guess for them going out is simply them being suffocated by smoke. Make sure the openings for smoke to leave the building is big enough to guarantee good "air"flow. If the smoke piles up, the fires can suffocate and simply go out until the smoke has gone away.

Yes, those are the fireplaces. Thanks for pointing out the smoke can cause fire to go out.

@MeanGreen Did you build the holes slightly differently from the ones in the video, or did the smoke behaviour change since that video was made? I'm just wondering if my answer is still valid :)

@Joachim Originally I built it exactly as in the video, before I asked the question. Yesterday I opened up the outside walls with the / and \ beams, replacing the square wall segments with | poles. The fires still go out.

I removed the roof section of one of the fires, and that fixes the problem, except when it rains. The flaw in my previous test was the fact the smoke doesn't generate on the floor level.
